# Simple quiz related software

Tags: windows, offline, game

I am about to have a triva night with a group of friends and since it was my turn this time around, I decided to go the extra mile.

Is there a software or app I can use that includes a place where I can add up to 80 questions, create lifelines and contain a timer?

I'm not looking for something costly and would prefer the program to be free, but I am open to all suggestions.

Comment: What Mobile OS? (Android, IOS, Windows phone)

Answer (score 1):

If you & your friends are writing the answers on pieces of paper, (or calling them out), you could use the [Libre Office](http://www.libreoffice.org/) [Impress](http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/impress/) presentation tool to create a series of timed slides with the questions on - for the Answers/marking session you could have the same slides with the answers transitioning in. You could, of course do the same with Power Point but it is not Open-Source.

You could even include media such as music or film clips in the questions and I am reasonably sure that you can display the timer on the slides, *possibly in some modes only*.

Answer (score 0):

Kahoot! (https://kahoot.com (organizers) / https://kahoot.it (players)) is popular in education for this purpose, and it allows you to create quizzes where the question and choices are displayed on a big screen, and people select the corresponding color on their devices.